# In scala how to wrap a PartialFunction?

Tags: scala

In scala, Futures have a sort of rescue function that takes a PartialFunction.  This code is skipped if the Future resolved with a response but is called if a failure occurs.

I want to simple wrap the partial function in a proxy that always executes code that writes to a stat counter.  At first I was thinking I would just create another PartialFunction but soon realized that does not work very well with the isDefined, then apply as I really want this to be called every time.

How do I go about proxying the PartialFunction such that my code is always called when the Future has an exception?

Comment: Do you want your function to execute for all failures, or no matter what?

Comment: for all failures only.

Comment: Why not use the `onFailure` callback instead?

Comment: @m-z oh, duh, I sohuld have thought of that.

Comment: `andThen` is also a decent option as it is a combinator vs `onComplete` which just returns a `Unit`.  You could build a `Future` factory that always adds an `andThen` to it for failure logging.

Answer (score 5):

To summarize the comments: You can use the `onFailure` callback to execute some side-effecting code (logging) when a `Future` fails.

```
val future = Future(1 / 0)

future.onFailure {
    case _ => println("I have seen the Future, and it doesn't look good.")
}
```

As @cmbaxter notes, you could also use `andThen` on the `Future`, which accepts a `PartialFunction[Try[A], B]` and returns the *original* `Future`. So you could apply the side-effecting function using `andThen`, and than `recover` afterwards. You could even chain them multiple times.

```
Future(1 / 0)
    .andThen { case Failure(_) => println("Future failed.") }
    .recover { case e: ArithmeticException => 0 }
    .andThen { case Failure(_) => println("Tried to recover, and still failed.") }
```

Or a helper that always includes it:

```
object FutureLogger {
     def apply[A](a: => A): Future[A] = Future(a).andThen {
         case Failure(_) => println("FAILURE")
     }
}
```